# Is there a URL in github that will show exactly the hash of the current HEAD?

Tags: git, github

I'd like to trigger builds based on whether or not my repository has changed. I was wondering if there were something like

```
https://github.com/my/repository/branch/master/HEAD
```

which would show just the sha1 of master's most recent commit.

Answer (score 2):

See https://api.github.com/repos/flevour/symfony/branches/master, parse the json and check for sha property.
In general, http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get-branch

Answer (score 1):

### Use service hooks

Rather than polling some feed, why not use [service hooks](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks) to send a request to your server/any server to perform <anything> whenever your repo is updated.

Answer (score 0):

you could maybe parse the rss feed

```
https://github.com/<username>/<repo>/commits/master.atom
```